# Communicate with application from Web

Tags: android, web-services, url, web-applications

I want to develop a website that allows me to manipulate my android phone afar, what can i use as a URL to link the 2 applications ? should i use webservices ?

Comment: Please explain what your trying to do - what you mean link; if you mean having Android work with a HTML mobile site - then go Phonegap or Titanium

Comment: yes i want to order my android mobile to send an SMS from my site for exemple. Is it possible without webservices or i have to use it ?

Comment: Titanium can do this. You can use the link to and fro. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766614/how-do-you-link-to-pages-windows-in-titanium-mobile-without-tabs

Comment: Can i communicate with my server using this ( I have no idea what Titanium can do ) i actually communicate witth my server using my IP @

Comment: You can communicate with the server yes. You can do this in Titanium inside a webview, use jQuery .load .get you can even use CUrl and PHP - an array of ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger special funktions like sending an sms or starting a call by using [special links](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links/)

**Examples for Android an iOS:**

```
<a href="wtai://wp/mc;123456789">Call 123456789</a>
<a href="sms:123456789*[?body=MESSAGE]">Send SMS</a>
```

Comment: same with apple.. tel: etc.. +1

Answer (score 0):

I see no way of direct communication with the native app. The website could send the requests to a server and than use [push notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) to trigger the changes in the native app.

Comment: thx but i don't want to use google appengine servers, i'm using apach servers and i just need a solution to get an URL that links my 2 applications

Comment: As long as we dont't know what kind of data you are trying to send between your app and the website i can't help you. I think you'll need a central server an something like push notifications for that. There is no direct way of communicating between the browser and a app.

Comment: yes i'm using apach server to exchange data between my 2 applications but i'm linking them with my ip @ since i work in local now

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices.

1. [RESTful services(they are like stripped down Web services)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)
2. [through json and php or whatever script you know](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)
3. [Google's Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

Since you seem eager to go with Web Services I suggest the first. It would be easier for you